# Factorials, Simplify the addition and multiplication of factorials.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

I have an equation containing factorials  here

$$(k+1)!+(k+1)(k+1)!$$

yet I am having a hard time understanding how to simplify it using algebra. A simple search on wolfram gets me a reduced form of

$$(k + 2)! $$

This would be a great refresher to such problems, sadly I don't know the elementary operations to reduce it.

Comment: Hint: $a+(k+1)a=(k+2)a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
 &(k + 1)! + (k + 1)(k + 1)!\\
= & (k + 1)!(1 + k + 1)\\
= & (k + 1)!(k + 2)\\
= & (k + 2)(k + 1)(k)(k - 1)....(1)\\
= & (k +2)!\\
\end{align}
First you factor out the $(k + 1)!$ and simplify $(1 + k + 1) = (k + 2)$.
You are left with $(k + 2)(k + 1)!$ which is just $(k + 2)!$.

Comment: I did not see that. Especially the last three steps, where you an simply remove K + 1  in the third step.

Answer (score 2):

Factor out the $(k+1)!$:

$$(k+1)! + (k+1)(k+1)! = (1+k+1)(k+1)! = (k+2)(k+1)! = (k+2)!$$

Comment: You are factoring out $(k+2)!$, isn't it?